How to calculate the limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(1 + \sin(12x))}{\ln(1+\sin(6x))}$ without L'Hôpital's rule?
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(1+\sin12x)}{\ln(1+\sin6x)}
$$
I know it's possible to calculate this limit just by transforming it; I think you need to use the knowledge that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} = 1, \quad \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1
$$
But I can't make it work.
I have gotten to this place:
$$
\frac{\ln(1+\sin12x)}{\ln(1+\sin6x)} = \frac{\ln(1+\sin12x)}{\sin12x} \cdot \frac{\sin12x}{12x} \cdot \frac{12x}{\ln(1+\sin6x)}
$$
but have no idea what do further with that last term.
Any help is appreciated, I got hung up on this like an hour ago...

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Formatting suggestion:  \ln and \sin

Following your idea:
$$
\frac{\ln(1+\sin12x)}{\ln(1+\sin6x)} = \frac{\ln(1+\sin12x)}{\sin12x} \cdot \frac{\sin12x}{12x} \cdot 2 \cdot \frac{6x}{\sin6x} \cdot \frac{\sin6x}{\ln(1+\sin6x)} \xrightarrow{x\to0} 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = 2.
$$

That's it! It didn't come to mind you could just reverse the limits to get what was needed. Thanks!

If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$,$\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exists then $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\cdot\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$
So you can separate your limit into the 3 limits we know
